# using TCP Keep-Alives in server to get rid of idle client

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

I have a **server** to collect **Tcp data** from different clients to a certain port. I have a scenario that whenever the client creates tcp connection and remain idle for more than **let's say 30 min** then I need to close the connection.

I have learned about **TCP keep alive** to track that the peer is dead or not and Mostly I found examples  used in client side. Similarly can I used in the server side to poll the connection whether it is active or not?

Further In **linux sysctl.conf** , there is a configuration file to edit the values. This seems that the whole tcp connection is destroyed after certain inactivity. I am in need such that certain connection form the device are destroyed after certain time inactivity but not the whole tcp port connection closed.

I am using **ubuntu** to create the server to collect tcp connection. Can I use **TCP Keep-Alives** in server code to find the inactive client and close the particular client? or is there any other way in server side to implement such feature?

and while going through the web it is mentioned that

```
(getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, &optlen)
```

this getsockopt is for the main tcp connection and setting here seems the setting is for whole connection to the server.

However what I need is for the specific client. I have the event server code as 
here **client_fd** is accepted and now I need to close this client_fd if next data through this client is not received within certain time.

```
void event_server(EV_P_ struct ev_io *w, int revents) {
    int flags;
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);

    int client_fd;

    // since ev_io is the first member,
    // watcher `w` has the address of the 
    // start of the _sock_ev_serv struct
    struct _sock_ev_serv* server = (struct _sock_ev_serv*) w;
    server->socket_len = len;

    for (;;) {
        if ((client_fd = accept(server->fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len)) < 0) {
            switch (errno) {
            case EINTR:
            case EAGAIN:
                break;
            default:
                zlog_info(_c, "Error accepting connection from client \n");
                //perror("accept");
            }
            break;
        }
        char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.sin6_addr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        char *dev_ip = get_ip(ip);
        server->device_ip = dev_ip;

        zlog_debug(_c,"The obtained ip is %s and dev_ip is %s", ip, dev_ip);

        /** check for the cidr address for config_ip **/
        char *config_ip;
        config_ip = get_config_ip(dev_ip, _client_map);
        zlog_debug(_c,"The _config ip for dev_ip:%s is :%s", dev_ip, config_ip);
        if (config_ip == NULL) {
            zlog_debug(_c,"Connection attempted from unreigistered IP: %s", dev_ip);
            zlog_info(_c, "Connection attempted from unregistered IP : %s", dev_ip);
            AFREE(server->device_ip);            
            continue;
        }

        json_t *dev_config;
        dev_config = get_json_object_from_json(_client_map, config_ip);
        if (dev_config==NULL) {
            zlog_debug(_c,"Connection attempted from unreigistered IP: %s", dev_ip);
            zlog_info(_c, "Connection attempted from unregistered IP : %s", dev_ip);
            AFREE(server->device_ip);
            continue;
        }

        if ((flags = fcntl(client_fd, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0 || fcntl(client_fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
            zlog_error(_c, "fcntl(2)");
        }


        struct _sock_ev_client* client = malloc(sizeof(struct _sock_ev_client));
        client->device_ip = dev_ip;
        client->server = server;
        client->fd = client_fd;

        // ev_io *watcher = (ev_io*)calloc(1, sizeof(ev_io));
        ev_io_init(&client->io, event_client, client_fd, EV_READ);
        ev_io_start(EV_DEFAULT, &client->io);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share more details about server creation process? i.e. how you creating servers?

Answer (score 2):

TCP keep alives are not to detect idle clients but to detect dead connections, i.e. if a client crashed without closing the connection or if the line is dead etc. But if the client is only idle but not dead the connection is still open. Any attempts to send an empty packet (which keep-alive packets are) to the client will result in an ACK from the client and thus keep alive will not report a dead connection.

To detect idle clients  instead use either timeouts for read (SO_RCVTIMEO) or use a timeout with select, poll or similar functions.

Comment: timeout while using in creating socket is actually as a whole Right? There can be multiple client, so at a time some client is sending some connection data . so there is no time out as it is receiving data form some of the client.  However there can be some inactive connection as well. How can I detect in individual client level?

Comment: @user203119:  You are setting the socket option at the client socket, not the server socket and thus you detect it at the client level.

Comment: isn't there any way to detect the client inactivity from server side. as I am creating a syslog collector, thus I need to find the client inactivity from server side if possible.

Comment: @user203119: with libev you can use a timer which you restart whenever you receive new data. With select, loop you can use the timeout for these functions. With blocking recv you can use SO_RCVTIMEO. The meaning of "inactivity" is specific to your application so there can be no system wide setting for such thing.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented below mechanism to detect idle status on `Socket` IO activity.

My `Socket` is wrapped in some class like `UserConnection`. This class has one more attribute `lastActivtyTime`. Whenever I get a read on write on this `Socket`,  I will update this attribute.

I have one more background `Reaper` thread, which will iterate through all `UserConnection` objects and check for lastActivtyTime. ***If current time - lastActivtyTime is greater than configured threshold parameter like 15 seconds***, I will close the idle connection.

In your case, when you are iterating through all `UserConnections`, you can check ***client_id*** and your threshold of ***30 minutes inactivity*** to close idle connection.

Comment: Not really. I am talking about both write and read activities. And OP need to set this value for certain clients only. Common parameter does not make sense here. He can't achieve it without polling from server end.